# Bash - shorten script with function

Tags: bash

In my script I need to get the highest number of a file two times, so i wanted to create a function. This is the command in the script:

First time:

```
highest=$( ls $path.bak.* | sort -t"." -k2 -n | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\.(.*)/\1/')
```

Second time:

```
newhighest=$(ls $path.bak.* | sort -t"." -k2 -n | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\.(.*)/\1/')
```

Now my question:
How can I shorten this with a function?

Here my Input-Files:

- test.bak.1
- test.bak.2
- test.bak.3
- test.bak.4
- test.bak.5
- test.bak.6
- test.bak.7
- test.bak.8
- test.bak.9
- test.bak.10
- test.bak.11

Expected return: 11

Comment: Use Syntax Highlighting to make it easier to read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Of course the *[don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)* rule applies here. Could you provide some sample input data (i.e. a  list of filenames) and confirm the result that you expect? And can you add some clarification around "highest number of a file two times"? It sounds as if your files are numbered. Do you just want the two highest numbered files that match your glob?

Comment: I am doing a backup-script. 
Sample files:
test.bak.1
test.bak.2
test.bak.3
test.bak.4
test.bak.5
test.bak.6
test.bak.7
test.bak.8
test.bak.9
test.bak.10
test.bak.11

Expected result:
11

I need this result as an integer in a variable.

@ghoti

PS: I am a bash newbie ;)

Comment: @Lukashoi, if it's worth including in your question, click the "edit" link under your question and *include it*. Comments are a terrible place for text that should be formatted.

Comment: @M.Becerra, please avoid linking the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated information. The [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) also covers functions, and so of course does the [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written out for readability:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - Ensure that this script is run with bash, not /bin/sh

# Enable "extended globs", so we can exclude names that don't end with digits
shopt -s extglob

# since your files are test.bak.*
path=test

get_highest() {
  # set the function's argument list
  set -- "$path".bak.+([[:digit:]])

  # if we have just one valid filename, we know the glob expanded successfully.
  # otherwise, no such files exist, so exit the function immediately
  [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] || return 1

  # stream our list of extensions into sort, and let awk find the highest number
  printf '%s\n' "${@##*.}" | awk '$0>last{last=$0}END{print last}'
}

highest=$(get_highest) || { echo "No backup files found" >&2; exit 1; }
new_highest=$(get_highest) || { echo "No backup files on 2nd pass" >&2; exit 1; }
```

---

Note:

- Expansions need to be quoted; `"$path"/*`, not `$path/*`, or else `path="Directory With Spaces/test"` would look for files in `Spaces/test`, after emitting `Directory` and `With` as results.
- [`ls` should never be used programatically.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [`extglob` syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) allows regex-like capabilities for matching groups of files, letting us assert here that we only consider filenames that end in `.bak.` followed by a digit.
- In general, you should write your scripts to be easy to read and understand as a higher priority than writing them to be short. Your future self (and others who need to maintain code in the future) will thank you.
- Because newlines can contain in filenames, they're unsafe to use to *separate* filenames in a stream; only the NUL character is safe for this use when names are not otherwise quoted or escaped. Thus, when emitting a stream of arbitrary names they should be formatted with the string `%s\0` and sorted with the `-z` argument. **However**, we're only printing the numeric extensions here, making newlines safe.

Comment: Would `awk '$0>last{last=$0}END{print last}'` be a reasonable replacement for your `sort | head` ?  It certainly seems to perform better for me...